# VMWare Workstation Ubuntu box: Expose minikube cluster to Windows host

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtual-machine, vmware

I'm running VMWare Workstation from Windows 10 with an Ubuntu 18.04 guest.

I am running a `minikube` cluster on the guest locally -- I can access it inside the guest at `http://192.168.99.100:30343`

After this, I have mapped it to localhost via: `kubectl proxy --port=30343` -- I can now access it as `localhost:30343`

However, this IP is not exposed to the host. If I go to `http://192.168.99.100:30343` from the host, it will time out.

If I do `ping 192.168.99.100` from the host, I get a reply:

```
ping 192.168.31.128

Pinging 192.168.31.128 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.31.128: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.31.128: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.31.128: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
```

But, going to `192.168.31.128:30343` in my host's browser yields a timeout, whereas going to `localhost:30343` inside the Ubuntu guest yields a page as intended.

How do I fetch the page from the host?

Answer (score 1):

Try this : sudo ufw disable. This command disable Ubuntu Firewall

[image: Network State]

Comment: With your exact setup - firewall disabled, bridges connection - I have no network at all. With the "NAT:" option and the firewall disabled, I have internet/network, but I cannot see any services from the host still.

Comment: I can, by the way, ping the local IP from the host and get a response. And I can access this specific web app from https://localhost:30343 from the guest. Yet if I access the URL of the guest IP + port.. It doesn't open :-/

Comment: Did you find any solution for this one ? Cheers !